# Модель прогнозирования потока поступающих. Временной ряд

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, анализ-данных, jupyter-notebook

Имеется такой набор данных

[image: Набор данных]

- School- Номер школы;
- ALL - Кол-во выпускников;
- e(год) - количество
  пришедших для поступления из этой школы

Необходимо обучить модель что бы она предсказывала сколько в 2021 году будет поступающих по каждой школе.

Насколько я понимаю это регрессия временного ряда. Но как обработать такие данные и сделать по ним прогноз совсем не представляю.
Буду рад любой помощи.

Comment: Надо ведь учитывать демографическую пирамиду ещё обязательно.

Comment: @КириллМалышев к сожалению имеются только такие данные

Comment: Это открытые данные, доступные всем.

Comment: И данные какие-то очень странные у вас. Между годами порядки сильно меняются.

Comment: @КириллМалышев я понимаю, но это задача из учебного проекта и мне нужно именно с этими данными что-то сделать. Точность модели не так важна, важнее что бы она просто могла предсказывать на основе вводимых в будущем номера школы и количества выпускников

Comment: Пусть задача из учебного проекта. Тем более попробуйте объяснить хотя бы себе: в school №22 у вас 1 миллион 130 тысяч 446 выпускников. А в школе 34 почти пол миллиона выпускников. Вас ничего не настораживает?